# PHP и базы данных. Не видит файл bd_params!

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Я полный новичок, поэтому не обессудьте. Пытаюсь установить соединение с БД и хочу получить параметры подключения из файла, а он его не видит, как решить, помогите!!
[[image: ошибка1]

[image: Файл с параметрами]

Comment: `$paramsPath = __DIR__."/../config/db_params.php"`

Comment: @InDevX на самом деле это костыль.

Comment: Если редактор не может найти файл, это еще ничего не значит. Код надо не разглядывать на картинке, а **запускать**. При запуске код находит файл или выдаёт ошибку? **Какую?** Сама константа `ROOT` **определена**?  Где? Как?

Comment: @Ипатьев так-то я такое только во всяких туториалах встречал и в универе. Но почему костыль?

Comment: @InDevX Ну потому что по факту же это относительный путь - путь относительно текущего скрипта. То есть он зависит от текущего расположения. если скажем расположение корневой папки проекта поменяется, например все эти причиндалы уедут за корень сайта, как это принято делать, или скажем поменяется структура проекта, то файл опять пропадёт. поэтому и рекомендуется использовать абсолютный путь не только технически, но и фактически - то есть не зависящий от текущего. И с независимой константой ROOT будет правильнее. Главное чтобы она была определена. Хотя даже и с ней плохо :)

Comment: @Ипатьев Какую константу не используй - всегда можно так поменять, что перестанет работать.. Может, тогда подключение файлов это, в принципе, огромный костыль?

Comment: @InDevX если это троллинг, то неудачный. Да, можно в такую позу поставить программу, что всё слетит. Но это не повод писать кривой код по принципу "все равно сломается". Вообще любой хардкод, любые магические числа и строковые значения прямо в коде - это плохо. По-хорошему, конфиг должен подключаться или вообще не здесь, или по крайней мере путь к нему должен быть прописан не прямо при вызове.

Comment: @Ипатьев не угадали, это сарказм был

Comment: @InDevX забыл сразу ответить, спасибо, помогло, теперь все работает :)